# Display a message if a page break occurs when printing HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on an web application that generates quotes. At the end of a quote, there's a « Details & Conditions » block that I don't want to be split upon printing. To that end, I use this CSS code:

```
@media print {
    #conditions {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

However, when the block is moved to the next page, it may not be clear for the client that there's more to read on the other side of the page.

Thus, I'd like to add a message on the main page when this happens. Something like « Details & conditions on the next page ». But I can't think of a way to know when to display this message, for this I would need to know that a page break occurred and I can't find a way to do that since it's a browser thing.

The HTML code is generated by a mix of PHP (server-side) and JavaScript (client-side) code, so I have quite some flexibility.

Any idea?

Comment: What about numbering pages with 1/2 and 2/2?

Comment: Since I don't know when page breaks occur, I can't number pages myself. For this I would have to rely on the user to properly set up the print options and I would like as much as possible the quote to be printable out of the box. Moreover, some browsers (e.g., Chrome) don't even allow the user to define headers and footers, they can only be shown/hidden.

Comment: You should know since the A4 paper size is well known.. You can try to make some consideration upon page height.. Or, you can print it as PDF, then you have the automatic page numbering